# Set state of react component before mount with firebase data

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to setState of my component before it mounts (in the cmoponentWillMount) with data I pull from Firebase but I am getting an error saying "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined. How do I properly set the state so that my component loads with the proper data?

```
componentWillMount(){
  const rootRef = fire.database().ref('groups')
  rootRef.limitToFirst(1).once('value', function(snap) {
    snap.forEach(function(child){
      var first = (child.val()).id;
      console.log(first);
      this.setState({ selectedGroupId: first });
    })
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Never do setState in loop and you get that error because you are using regular function so change it to arrow function like below. Also switch to componentDidMount method because componentWillMount is deprecated

```
  componentDidMount(){
      const rootRef = fire.database().ref('groups')
      rootRef.limitToFirst(1).once('value', snap => {
      let first = 0;
      snap.forEach(child => {
          first = (child.val()).id;
          console.log(first);
     })
     this.setState({ selectedGroupId: first });
     });
  }
```

Or bind it like this if you don’t like to use an arrow function

```
   componentDidMount(){
         const rootRef = fire.database().ref('groups')
         rootRef.limitToFirst(1).once('value', function(snap) {
              let first = 0;
              snap.forEach(function(child){
                    first = (child.val()).id;
                    console.log(first);
               }.bind(this));
             this.setState({ selectedGroupId: first });
            }.bind(this));
     }
```

Start using let & const instead of var.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the scope for **this** is undefined. You need to pass it through with ES6 arrow functions.

```
componentWillMount(){
  const rootRef = fire.database().ref('groups')
  rootRef.limitToFirst(1).once('value', (snap) => {
    snap.forEach((child) => {
      var first = (child.val()).id;
      console.log(first);
      this.setState({ selectedGroupId: first });
    })
  });
}
```

Try it this way.

Comment: Also, componentWillMount is considered legacy at this point. You should try using componentDidMount instead.